# C++ testing for \n

Tags: c++, char, std

I'm attempting to learn C++ and one exercise is to build a command line tool that accepts user input and stores it in a char array until the user enters a blank line. I think I have the skeleton right but for whatever reason my while runs continuously. My code is as follows:

```
    char a[256];

    //while the first character isn't a new line
    while (a[0] != '\n') {

        //get the char array
        cin >> a; 

        cout << a;

    }
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: If you're really trying to learn C++, put down whatever tutorial you're using, and buy a book that teaches you [how to do strings properly](http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/Resources).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't detect newlines with `operator>>`.  For most types, it uses whitespace as a delimiter, and it doesn't differentiate between spaces, tabs or newlines.  Use getline instead:

```
for (std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line); )
{
    if (line.empty())
    {
        // if the line is empty, that means the user didn't
        // press anything before hitting the enter key
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for starters: use a std::string instead of the char array and choose useful variable names.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    for(string text;getline(cin, text);) {
        if (!text.empty()) {
            cout << text << endl;
        } else {
           break;
        }      
    } 
}
```

Comment: Okay, now look at your output.  It doesn't stop on empty lines, like the OP is asking for.